# Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to load ZF2. Run `php composer.phar install` or define a ZF2_PATH environment variable.'

Tags: php, zend-framework, wamp

Installed WAMP.Copied Zend Framework in www folder.When I am trying to access 127.0.0.1.
Getting this error.Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have not installed composer, install it

```
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Run in project path

```
$ php composer.phar install
```

For Windows, install composer: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows
and run `php.exe composer.phar install`

Comment: Thanks mnv but now unable to set the include_path in php.ini as I am new to Zend please suggest me the path value to provide in php.ini.  @mnv